# How do I change the attributes of a UILabel with a custom programmatic UIView [Swift 5]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I'm designing a UI in Swift 5 programatically. Within the superview, I've added a subview called `viewLeft1` with the type `UIStackView`. Inside `viewLeft1`'s declaration, I've created a UILabel with some default attributes.

The declaration of `viewLeft1`

```
let viewLeft1: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    let lbl = UILabel()
    stackView.addSubview(lbl)
    lbl.text = "--"
        
    return stackView
}()
```

An example of a function that would change the `text` attribute of `lbl`

```
func updateLabel1() {
    // Change the lbl.text to "302"
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access `lbl` because it was defined within `viewLeft1`.

How could I achieve this? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather add another property for the label:

```
let label: UILabel = {
    let lbl = UILabel()
    lbl.text = "--"
    return lbl
}()

let viewLeft1: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    // configure other properties of stackView, such as constraints,
    // but don't add viewLeft1 to it here
    return stackView
}()
```

And then in the initialiser of the view, where you add `viewLeft1` to `self`, also add `label` to `viewLeft1`:

```
self.addSubview(viewLeft1)
viewLeft1.addArrangedSubview(label)
```